# How can I select an option from a drop down list on Chrome using VBA?

Tags: html, css, vba, selenium, web-scraping

'  Sub chromeAuto()

```
Dim obj As New WebDriver
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
obj.Start "chrome", ""
obj.Get "https://www.website.com/" #######Opens Chrome

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)

obj.FindElementById("userid").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
obj.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
obj.FindElementById("btnActive").Click'
```

##Logs into website

```
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
obj.FindElementById("pt1:_UIScmil2u::icon").Click
obj.FindElementById("pt1:_UIScmi4").Click
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 4, Now)
obj.FindElementById("pt1:r1:0:r0:0:r1:0:AP1:soc2::drop").Click #######Opens Drop down list
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)'
```

# Below is the source code I get from the button I want to select

I am trying to select option 2

```
  `<ul class="x1qz" id="pt1:r1:0:r0:0:r1:0:AP1:soc2::pop"><li id="pt1:r1:0:r0:0:r1:0:AP1:soc2::sp" 
   class="x1r4"></li>
   <li class="x1r8 p_AFSelected" _adfiv="0">Option 0</li>
   <li class="x1r8" _adfiv="1">Option 1</li>
   <li class="x1r8" _adfiv="2">Option 2</li>
   <li class="x1r8" _adfiv="3">Option 3</li>
   <li class="x1r8" _adfiv="4">Option 4</li>
   <li class="x1r8" _adfiv="5">Option 5</li>
   <li class="x1r8" _adfiv="6">Option 6</li>
   <li class="x1r8" _adfiv="7">Option 7</li>
   </ul>
   `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to know without seeing more html but try css attribute selector of

```
obj.findElementByCss("[_adfiv='2']").click
```